# Opacity/Translucency of a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jbutton, translucency

I have simple GUI code as follows, in which I want to make the `JButton` one translucent, so that the image behind the `JButton` is visible!

```
package dealORnodeal;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class Deal extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private Container contentPane = getContentPane();
private JButton one = new JButton("1"),two = new JButton("2");
private JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("JumpTo");
private JMenuBar bar1 = new JMenuBar();
private ImagePanel bg = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("bg.jpg").getImage());
public Deal()
{

    super("Deal Or No Deal");
    setSize(800,850);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(null);
    contentPane.add(bg);

    JMenuItem item1;

    item1 = new JMenuItem("Start Game");
    item1.addActionListener(this);
    menu1.add(item1);

    item1 = new JMenuItem("GoTo Rules");
    item1.addActionListener(this);
    menu1.add(item1);

    item1 = new JMenuItem("GoTo Credits");
    item1.addActionListener(this);
    menu1.add(item1);

    item1 = new JMenuItem("GoTo Menu");
    item1.addActionListener(this);

    menu1.add(item1);
    bar1.add(menu1);
    setJMenuBar(bar1);

    //GAME CODE
    one.setBounds(25,151,190,49);
    one.addActionListener(this);

    add(one);
    //GAME CODE END

setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{}
}
```

Now how would the code be if I wanted to set the button to be translucent so that the background image would be visible through the button. BTW please don't confuse Translucent with transparent!

Comment: I think this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373345/how-to-create-partly-transparent-jbutton-on-fully-transparent-jframe

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (add a `main(String])`, include `ImagePanel` & create an image in code).

Comment: Why not state the difference between translucence and transparence to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Have a look at this example [Translucent JButton](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11490905/1057230), not sure if this is what you wanted !!

Comment: try this http://manoharbhattarai.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/how-to-create-translucent-and-shaped-windows-in-java/

Comment: @GagandeepBali that was a wonderful link! +1

Comment: @GagandeepBali pls post this link as your answer, so that user can accept it.

Comment: don't do any manual sizing/locating (aka null layout) _ever_ - that's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment to your question, so I'll answer you here..

if you use this code:

```
myButton.setOpaque(false);
```

It would not paint the button - because now it's a trasnparent. 
to create the button translucent I think you should override the button paint method..

take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373345/how-to-create-partly-transparent-jbutton-on-fully-transparent-jframe)

Answer (score 1):

`setOpaque` doesn't work for JButtons, the right property is:

`button.setContentAreaFilled(false);`